# DateTimePicker Spaces out when Resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm having some problems when trying to make my page resize to mobile with the DateTimePicker for bootstrap. It's fine when it starts out full size but the moment I resize the window to a mobile-friendly size the input field and the span with glyphicon space themselves out.

This is what I have running for the datetimepicker:

```
<div class="panel-group" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" >
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-color:black;overflow:visible;">
        <div class="panel-body panel-controller">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon btn">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And upon resizing it to mobile it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GbCS.png

Any suggestions on what I can do to resolve this issue?

Thanks  in advance for the help!

Comment: I test your code with bootstrap without any changes and it works perfectly. http://www.bootply.com/VmuStJXeq2 Share your CSS that is affecting to this part to help you. Otherwise I can't get my crystal ball in this moment...

Comment: I made an edit and added the container that the datetimepicker was in. I am just using the standard bootstrap3 css, I haven't made any changes to it. I am wondering if it is the panel-group css that is making it do that upon resize because like your example they all seem to work not in this situation. @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Fixed it! Ended up having to change the default Visual Studio CSS. It had input { max-width:280px; }. So I just switched it to 100%

Comment: Oh man! I have nightmares with Visual Studio. Good luck